# How to change an individual pixel of an RGBA image?

Tags: image-processing, julia

In the below code I was trying to make the red component of the first pixel to be zero.

---

```
julia> image1 = load("background1.png");

julia> x = image1[1].r
0.776N0f8

julia> image1[1].r = 0
ERROR: type RGBA is immutable
```

Turns out the RGBA type in Julia is immutable. Is there a way I could change the individual pixels (R, G & B components) of an image?

Comment: Hi Mathomo, welcome to stackoverflow. You should make your title short and precise and put the actual question in the body rather than the title.

Comment: Thanks. I will do so next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a new RGB. It's cheap to do:

```
image1 = load("background1.png")
x = image1[1]
image1[1] = RGB(0,x.g,x.b)
```

Comment: Hey, if this worked then you should mark it as a solution so that others know it's solved. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all! Welcome to SO! You may want to find the [Julialang Slack](https://julialang.slack.com/) as well ([get an invite here](https://slackinvite.julialang.org/)). Also, the [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) is a good way to get help too. Hopefully you can get the help you need! Cheers.